# Consuming rabbitmq queue and inserting messages in Mysql on cloud?

Tags: php, push-notification, rabbitmq, publish-subscribe, appfog

I developed an android app where it subscribes to a queue and also publishes to other queues. At a time it publishes the same message to two different queues, one of them is a queue named "Queue" and now from a appfog instance i need to subscribe to the "Queue" and consume messages and insert them in a mysql db.

I created a php standalone app for the above purpose with codeigniter. By some reason the worker app loses its connection to rabbitmq. i would like to know the best way to do this. 
How can a worker app on appfog can sustain the application restarts.

what of kind of thing i need to use to solve the above problem.

Answer (score 0):

What version of RabbitMQ are you using? In 3.0 heartbeats were enabled by default for connections. If there is a regular disconnect (10 minutes by default) period then it is probably the heartbeat that is disconnecting.

Your client (hopefully) can configure a longer during the connection negotiation or you can have your PHP app send a heartbeat at a regular interval. [Here is the announcement post](http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2012/11/20/whats-new-in-rabbitmq-3-0/) that describes it a bit.

Comment: i figured that the problem is not with rabbitmq connection. it is with the code related to mysql inserts. i checked the crash logs of my app and the error is "Mysql gone away". an example of php rabbitmq consumer has call backs for receive message and register_shutdown. in receive call back i can not use $this of code igniter because its out of scope and i was using get_instance(). i am not sure how to call a method from rabbitmq client receive call back function.